# Invalid syntax for full text searching query?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm trying to encapsulate a full-text search query inside of a stored procedure. Here is the procedure creation code itself:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[fts]
    @query varchar, 
    @salesbase int
AS
    SELECT c1.* FROM CONTACT1 c1
        JOIN CONTACT2 c2 ON c1.ACCOUNTNO = c2.ACCOUNTNO
    WHERE c2.USLEBASE = @salesbase
    AND (
        CONTAINS(c1.COMPANY, @query) OR
        CONTAINS(c1.ADDRESS1, @query) OR
        CONTAINS(c1.CONTACT, @query)
    )
```

Invoking the stored procedure with the `@query` set to `'"*Donalds*"'` will return the following error:

```
EXECUTE [fts] @query = '"*Donalds*"', @salesbase = 410
> Syntax error near '"' in the full-text search condition '"'.
```

This is confusing to me because if I invoke the 'meat' of the stored procedure on it's own - using the exact same value - there's no syntax error.

```
SELECT c1.* FROM CONTACT1 c1
    JOIN CONTACT2 c2 ON c1.ACCOUNTNO = c2.ACCOUNTNO
WHERE c2.USLEBASE = 410
AND (
    CONTAINS(c1.COMPANY, '"*Donalds*"') OR
    CONTAINS(c1.ADDRESS1, '"*Donalds*"') OR
    CONTAINS(c1.CONTACT, '"*Donalds*"')
)
> (291 row(s) affected)
```

I must be missing something fundamental here. Any ideas?

Comment: This is just a hunch, but try `CONTAINS(c1.COMPANY, '"*'+ @query +'*"')` and remove the `"*` and `*"` parts from he variable itself.

Comment: According to SSMS this is a syntax error unto itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably declare the `varchar` variable with a specified length.
According to [this article](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) and the best of my knowledge, if you declare a `varchar` without a specific length, you are actually declaring `varchar(1)`.

This is also stated in [MSDN's page about char and varchar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx):

> When n is not specified in a data definition or variable declaration statement, the default length is 1. When n is not specified when using the CAST and CONVERT functions, the default length is 30.

Comment: Bizarrely, this fixes the issue.

I think I'll stick to Javascript from now on.

Comment: sql is not harder then javascript, it's just different :-)

Comment: I didn't claim it was harder, just that I don't like it. :(